# Site header width differences in WordPress: Why is my author page incomplete?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have differences in site header width between author page and other pages, it appears not complete in author page white it's complete in other pages, what I missing ?

```
            <header id="site-header" role="banner" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WPHeader">
                <?php
                // Elementor `header` location.
                if ( ! function_exists( 'elementor_theme_do_location' ) || ! elementor_theme_do_location( 'header' ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <div class="container clear">
                        <div class="site-branding">
                            <?php if ( has_custom_logo() ) { ?>
                                <?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                                    <h1 class="logo site-title" itemprop="headline">
                                        <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
                                    </h1><!-- END #logo -->
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <h2 class="logo site-title" itemprop="headline">
                                        <?php the_custom_logo(); ?>
                                    </h2><!-- END #logo -->
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                                <?php if ( is_front_page() || is_home() || is_404() ) { ?>
                                    <h1 id="logo" class="site-title" itemprop="headline">
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                                    </h1><!-- END #logo -->
                                <?php } else { ?>
                                    <h2 id="logo" class="site-title" itemprop="headline">
                                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
                                    </h2><!-- END #logo -->
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </div><!-- .site-branding -->
```

I did a lot of css edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Author Page the `body` HTML element has the CSS class `author` which adds a margin left and right to the entire page. This is what makes the header appear out of place too.

```
.author {
    margin-right: 15px!important;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Removing the CSS Class from the `body` element should fix this.